# Problem loading sqldf and SQLite packages

Tags: r, r-package, sqldf, rsqlite

I'd like to use the `sqldf()` function. However, after installing the package, when I load it I receive this error:

```
install.packages("sqldf", dep = TRUE)
library("sqldf")
> Loading required package: RSQLite
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLite’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
Error: package ‘RSQLite’ could not be loaded
```

Then, when I try to install and load the `RSQLite` package I receive this one:

```
> library(RSQLite)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSQLite’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
```

I would appreciate it if you could share experience on this one.

p.s: I tried to use `update.packages()` it did not work either.

Comment: Try `install.packages('vctrs')`. It looks like the newest version is missing.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your R session? Make sure not to re-load any packages and try updating `vctrs`: `install.packages("vctrs")`

Comment: I tried your suggestions, still nothing. :(

Comment: What does "still nothing" mean exactly? Exacty same error message? What happened when you ran "install.packages()"? What version of `vctrs` to you currently have installed?

Comment: I restarted my R session and did load the `vctrs` library. Then, I loaded other packages (RSQLite, sqldf) and got the same errors.

Comment: See if the suggestions in the comments under this post work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174542/r-error-when-trying-to-load-the-sqldf-package